# Do “because so-and-so claims that” and “claiming that” have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, differences, gerunds

First, I would like to give an example.

> She filed a complaint to the committee **because she claims that** her personal information was leaked.
>
> She filed a complaint to the committee **claiming that** her personal information was leaked.

So, do “because she claims that” and “claiming that” have the same meaning? Why or why not?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences could have the same meaning, but it depends on how the grammar of the second sentence is interpreted.

In your first sentence, *because she claims that her personal information was leaked* is an ***adjunct of reason***, stating ***why*** she filed a complaint to the committee.

In your sencond reason, *claiming that her personal information was leaked* is a gerundial non-finite clause  which can be interpreted in 3 ways as:

1. attributive, modifying the noun ***complaint***, stating ***what kind of complaint*** she filed.
2. an adjunct of manner, stating ***in what way*** she filed the complaint.
3. an ***adjunct of reason***, stating ***why*** she filed a complaint to the committee.

If you chose the 1st interpretation you can understand:

> She filed a complaint to the committee ***which claims*** / ***in which she claims*** that her personal information was leaked.

If you chose the 2nd interpretation, then the sentence has the meaning:

> She filed a complaint to the committee ***(by)*** claiming that her personal information was leaked.

Finally, if you chose the 3rd interpretation then yes, the two sentences are synonymous, and you can move *claiming that her personal information was leaked* at the beginning of the sentence:

> *Claiming (because she claims...)* that her personal information was leaked, she filed a complaint to the committee.

Comment: The two sentences differ **in meaning**, but this difference in meaning doesn't make much **practical** difference in the OP's example: although the first version does not strictly speaking say that the claims appear within the complaint, most people would, upon hearing it, assume that they do.

Comment: I believe the grammatical structure of the second sentence **is** ambiguous.

Comment: I agree with @jsw29 -  in the first sentence, the contents of the complaint is unknown (we are just told what prompted her to write it), while it is explicit in the second that the complaint contains the claim that her information was leaked.

Comment: I agree with @fev on this answer - “by” is ambiguous without further context, though (1) and (3) are stronger than (2) because “filing” complaints is normally a formal process while “claiming” something sounds less formal.